# How to deserialize an array of objects when the first item is the count of items to follow

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following problem with deserializing json to c#-objects.

I have a json-string, something like this:

```
string data = 
@"{
    'response':
        [
            3,
            {
                'id': 1, 
                'name': 'john'
            },
            {
                'id': 1, 
                'name': 'john'
            },
            {
                'id': 1, 
                'name': 'john'
            }
        ]
 }";
```

And classes for deserialization:

```
class Response 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "response")]
    Item[] Items {get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id{get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public int Id{get; set; }
}
```

And then i try to deserialize it:

```
 var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(data);
```

Deserialization rases an exception with following message: **"Error converting value 3 to type 'Item'. Path 'response[0]', line 1, position 19."**
 Obvioiusly it happend because array 'response' in data string contains literal "3" that describes a response's length. I would like to know, can i do deserialization corretly without writing custom deserialization logic, by means of json.net only? Or do i need to create custom deserialization logic?

Comment: your json is not of the expected format. The number 3 in the array is treated as a member, while it probably intends to denote the length of the array. It is being wrongly interpreted by the json deserializer. If you remove it from the JSON you will be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your model should be corrected a little bit

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "response")]
    Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you remove the `3` from your json this deserialization will work correctly

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```

if it comes from a server you have no control on it then you can write a custom converter

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Item);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value is long)
        {
            reader.Read(); //Skip this 3
            serializer.Converters.Remove(this); //avoid infinite recursion
        }
        return serializer.Deserialize<Item>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and deserialize as

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json, new CustomConverter());
```

---

You can even use Linq to get list of `Items`

```
var items = JObject.Parse(json)["response"]
                .Skip(1)
                .OfType<JObject>()
                .Select(j=>j.ToObject<Item>())
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach,

```
   class Response
    {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "response")]
    public dynamic Items { get; set; }
    }


    var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(data);
    var result = (des.Items as IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>)
              .Select(delegate(JToken j){

        if (j.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
            return j.Value<int>();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(j.ToString());

    }).ToList();

    var one = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(result[1].ToString());
```